# Long Ride on Horseback through Europe

Tags: wild-camping, human-waste, horses

I am riding on Horseback from Southern Denmark via Germany and France to Southern Spain.
I hope to rely on the goodwill of farmers for an overnight camp spot and grazing for my two horses. But what about forest and wilderness areas?
I am an experienced wilderness traveller and believe in the adage "Take nothing but your photos and memories and leave nothing but your footprints (HOOF prints)

Comment: OK, so what exactly is your question?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: how do you handle the veterinary papers for all the border crossings? That's a major hassle for even one border. I assume that you have to get a new health certificate for each border crossing?

Comment: * Is the horse coming from a European Union country?
* Are you going through non European Union countries?
* Does the horse already have a certificate from a European vet?
* Does the horse have a passport? You may wish to contact someone on this site
http://ec.europa.eu Here is a page for horses on the above site http://ec.europa.eu/food/animals/identification/equine/index_en.htm